# Is it correct to put 'the' before uncaring?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

There was an article on local daily titled **'To all the uncaring people'.**
Is it correct to put **the** before uncaring?
Your take on this.

Comment: Both are grammatical and correct: "To all the uncaring people" and "To all uncaring people".  The nuance of meaning may be slightly different, but you need not worry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to EL&U.

Yes it is perfectly correct to put the definite article before "uncaring" because "uncaring" is an adjective describing "people".

If I wrote "To all the tall people", "To all the white people", "To all the Chinese people" and so on I would expect you to have no problem with that because the structure ARTICLE+ADJECTIVE+NOUN is a very common one in English, it's like saying "I like the blue vases" or "Look at the fast cars"

I suspect that you are confused because "uncaring" looks like a verb, but it isn't. It is related to the verb 'to care' which has the present participle 'caring' and which can be used as a verb in sentences like "He is caring for his sick wife" meaning that he is looking after her but 'caring' can also be used as an adjective in sentences like "She is a very caring person" which means that she is a person with a lot of empathy and love for others.

"Uncaring" is the opposite of "caring" when used as an adjective and so it is an adjective itself. It's not a verb because there would have to be an infinitive form "to uncare" which has not yet been used as far as I know and, if it has it is very rare and I'm not quite sure what it would mean.

So "To all the uncaring people" is perfectly OK, it just says that the writer is addressing the people who are the opposite of "caring". That is those who have a lack of empathy and love for some group of other people. "The suffering people" perhaps as 'suffering' can also be used as an adjective.

Comment: 'I like the blue vases' and 'I like blue vases' are far from synonymous; inclusion of the article is acceptable (and required) in the context of some identified subset of blue vases (the three in a painting of a ceramics display, perhaps). However, 'To all the uncaring / tall ...  people' and  'To all uncaring / tall ... people', where the universal set defaults to mankind, _are_ merely style choices.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's true but the occasions when the universal set is in use are very few. If Xi Jinping were to give a speech in English in which he said "I am speaking to all the Chinese people" and another in which he said "I am speaking to all Chinese people" the first would refer to the citizens of the PRC and the second to them and to the members of the diaspora. Also if a charity spokesperson referred to "all _the_ uncaring people in the world" there would still be a slight difference of emphasis between that and  "all uncaring people in the world".

Comment: If Xi Jinping were to give a speech in English in which he said "I am speaking to all the Chinese people" .... Not necessarily; emphasising 'all the Chinese' informs the diaspora sense.  Article usage is _very_ complex; Cobuild have a 100+ page monograph on it. And it doesn't cover the use of a/n with non-count nouns, or Master's work on the null versus zero article.